# Is it possible to trigger a mail if the validation fails using spring integration?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch, jakarta-mail

Is it possible to trigger mail using spring integration if my validation fails in `.handle("validateDeal", "validate")` step? I have a scenario where i poll for files , check for a specific format for the file , if it's not in a specific format i need to trigger the mail and stop the process , if the file name is in a specific format i run the spring batch job i.e `.transform(fileMessageToJobRequest())`
So basically if validation fails , i want to send a mail (???), if validation passes i want to trigger my spring batch job i.e `.transform(fileMessageToJobRequest())`, 
is it possible to do everything in the same integration flows?

Please let me know, if possible please tell me some code snippet using `integrationflows(java dsl)`

```
 Below is my code:-

@Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;


    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow inboundFileIntegration(@Value("${inbound.file.poller.fixed.delay}") long period,
                                                  @Value("${inbound.file.poller.max.messages.per.poll}") int maxMessagesPerPoll,
                                                  TaskExecutor taskExecutor,
                                                  MessageSource<File> fileReadingMessageSource,
                                                 JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway) {



        return IntegrationFlows.from(fileReadingMessageSource,
                c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(period)
                        .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
                        .maxMessagesPerPoll(maxMessagesPerPoll)))
                         .channel(ApplicationConfiguration.INBOUND_CHANNEL) 
.handle("validateDeal", "validate")                  
.transform(fileMessageToJobRequest())
.handle(jobLaunchingGateway())
 .channel(MessageChannels.queue())
                 .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public FileMessageToJobRequest fileMessageToJobRequest() {
        FileMessageToJobRequest fileMessageToJobRequest = new FileMessageToJobRequest();
        fileMessageToJobRequest.setFileParameterName("input.file.name");
      //  fileMessageToJobRequest.setJob(personJob());
        System.out.println("FilePollingIntegrationFlow::fileMessageToJobRequest::::Job launched successfully!!!");
        return fileMessageToJobRequest;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway() {
        SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
      //  simpleJobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        simpleJobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SyncTaskExecutor());
        JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway = new JobLaunchingGateway(simpleJobLauncher);
        System.out.println("FilePollingIntegrationFlow::jobLaunchingGateway::::Job launched successfully!!!");
        return jobLaunchingGateway;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the `.filter()` is your choice with its `discardChannel` option:

```
 * Specify a channel where rejected Messages should be sent. If the discard
 * channel is null (the default), rejected Messages will be dropped. However,
 * the 'throwExceptionOnRejection' flag determines whether rejected Messages
 * trigger an exception. That value is evaluated regardless of the presence
 * of a discard channel.
 * @param discardChannel the discardChannel.
 * @return the endpoint spec.
 * @see MessageFilter#setDiscardChannel(MessageChannel)
```

The code might like this:

```
.filter(validateDeal, "validate", e -> e.discardChannel("discardChannel"))
```

The `validate` must return `boolean` value. When its `true` the message is passed to the downstream, otherwise it goes to that `discardChannel`. The email sending logic you can do in the flow on that `discardChannel` using `Mail.outboundAdapter()`.

There is another way to configure the same:

```
.filter(validateDeal, "validate", e -> e.discardFlow(sf -> sf.handle(Mail.outboundAdapter())))
```

See their JavaDocs for more information and read Reference Manual.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#filter

Comment: Thanks for your reply , can you please prototype some code seeing my code snippet ,it will help , as I am new to spring integration. Basically where to introduce the filter in my flow.

Comment: Ok. Tomorrow in the morning

Comment: I've just added a sample into my answer.

Comment: Thanks for replying,  So i can still do my validate logic in the below way:-@Component
public class ValidateDeal { @ServiceActivator
        public String validate(String payload){...}, please let me know

Comment: ??? No you can't. I told you: the `validate()` must return `boolean`. Your `payload` (request Message) isn't touched at all. Please, read the Reference Manual I've pointed above.

Comment: I got it , something like below:- public class PetFilter {
    ...
    @Filter  1
    public boolean dogsOnly(String input) {
        ...
    }
}

Comment: Thanks a lot Artem, How to implement Mail.outboundAdapter() , any code snippet will help

Comment: Not sure what you would like to get from me on the matter. The is a Doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/mail.html#mail-outbound. That `Mail.outboundAdapter()` has JavaDocs with appropriate links to other classes for their JavaDocs. We also have some sample on the matter: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/mail. That's all. Nobody here is going to code for you.